# Using pipenv with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, dependency-management, pipenv

I currently have an Anaconda distribution of Python 3.6.8 running on a windows 10 machine.
My projects reside in conda virtual environments and each have their own requirements.txt to specify
packages and versions. I wish to achieve better dependency resolution by utilizing pipfile and pipfile.loc
which is made possible by pipenv. Is it possible to combine conda and pipenv to achieve this?
And is this the best or recommended way to resolve package versioning dependencies?

But is it the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's subjective. I have Anaconda, but only out of necessity. I find that it is unreliable at times. I use virtualenv for my projects and I have never had an issue with them. They are reliable and I haven't seen a need to jump ship for a fad.

My advise is to experiment, but if you need something to work reliably, virtualenv is a strong contender. The old adage comes to mind, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: virtualenv and pip bundles nicely into pipenv I would say. And how do you specify package dependencies? requirements.txt , or ?

Comment: Yes, I use pip to install/create requirements.txt

Comment: And how do you achieve dependency resolution between packages and versions? manually ? testing and then updating requirements?

Comment: I guess it depends on what I'm working with/on. Maybe I've been lucky because I haven't had too many conflicts. If I did, it's usually jumping down a version, which I found out by testing. So, I guess a little manual and testing. pip by itself seems to do a good job of warning if a certain version is incompatible or if I need a specific version not yet installed. I usually update requirements at the end of the day and end of a project, but only after all packages are copacetic.

Comment: _I find that it is unreliable at times._  I know I'm late to the party, but can you expand on that?

Comment: Overall, Anaconda is great for the base installation, although I use Miniconda to cut down on packages. Plus, I don't need administrative rights to install, but I don't have administrative rights. When I try to use a different environment with Anaconda, other than root, it hemmed and hawed. It wasn't a pleasant experience. I could have made it work and fought through it, but when I just use vitrualenv...it just works...with no push back. It does what I want, when I want it, and as expected. With Anaconda, It may let you do what you want, but it's in control...at least that is the way I see it.